# Gitlab backup and restore

Tags: backup, gitlab, restore

I want to backup gitlab and restore it on another server. How to do it? I tried nothing till now just asking for help and suggestions. I read gitlab documentation , in the document they are telling to backup /etc/gitlab/gitlab-secret.json but i my system gitlab is installed in /opt and i couldn fine .json file ? And i am using centos.

Comment: Did you install with the Omnibus?

Comment: @BrokenBinary I don't how it was installed ,it is already setup and i just have to take backup and restore it to another git lab . How to find out if omnibus is installed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read gitlab documentation , in the document they are telling to backup /etc/gitlab/gitlab-secret.json but i my system gitlab is installed in /opt and i couldn fine .json file ?

If you installed from source, the secret file will be at `/home/git/gitlab/.secret`.  The JSON file would only exist in an omnibus installation.

> How to do it?

The [backup & restore docs](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html) are pretty good.  Follow the steps and, if you have any trouble, please ask.

Comment: I read this documentation but couldn't understand, i am running git lab on Centos 6 so none of the commands given for backup works please help me out and git lab is installed in **/opt/git lab 7.6.1-0/** . None of the command works given in the document. And i also want to install git lab on another Centos where i have to restore but first i have to take backup which i am not able to do. Will the repositories of old Git lab version work in new Git lab like version 8?

Comment: I tried finding **.secret** by  ` find / -name ".secret" ` the output:
**/opt/gitlab-7.6.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/.secret**
**/opt/gitlab-7.6.1-0/apps/gitlabcli/htdocs/.secret**

Comment: Check this Image 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Fw6rqXV_FBUmQzQThSUS1OSDg

Sorry for too many comments just need too clear my doubts.

Comment: For the first image, you copied the command wrong and didn't include the `sudo`.  In both images, you're also in the wrong directory to be running the `bundle` command.  Run `ls -al /home/git/gitlab` and `ls -al /etc/gitlab` to first find the correct secrets file. Do you see either a `gitlab-secrets.json` or `.secret` file in either directory?

Comment: I am sharing all the  screen shots just have a look .

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Fw6rqXV_FBbXYtZ1JmeHNCSkU/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Fw6rqXV_FBQXNQQzlvQVlJYUk

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Fw6rqXV_FBbnhoTEQ2ODhFVkE

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Fw6rqXV_FBZHo5NHZKczltUDQ

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Fw6rqXV_FBTFpzdWg2OEI5VWs

Comment: In the last image you can find `.secret` file which is in `ls -al /opt/gitlab-7.6.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/`

Comment: `# cd /opt/gitlab-7.6.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/
  # sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
sudo: bundle: command not found`

Shows bundle command not found error.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info` and `find / -name 'gitlab.rb' -print`?

Comment: `# find / -name 'gitlab.rb' -print`

`/opt/gitlab-7.6.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/html-pipeline-gitlab-0.1.5/lib/html/pipeline/gitlab.rb`

`/opt/gitlab-7.6.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/docker/gitlab.rb`

Comment: `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info` the output is `sudo: gitlab-rake: command not found`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way your instance is setup.  I would suggest testing the backup-restore on a vm first.  Copy `/opt/gitlab-7.6.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/.secret`.  Run `cd /opt/gitlab-7.6.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/ ; sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production`.  If this doesn't create the backup, try [this link](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/migrate-7-6-2-to-last-omnibus/808/2).  If you still have no luck, I suggest speaking to the admin that setup your gitlab instance.

Comment: If nothing else works, you can try asking on the [gitlab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/).